# String object creations in java

Tags: java

Q.1. How many Objectes are created in the below example?
   ex.

```
String s1="isaq";
String s2="isaq";
String s3="isaq";
```

if answer is 1 or 3 ,explain me why?

Comment: if answer is 1 or 3 ,explain me why? So if the answer is 2 you don't want to have an explaination? ^^

Comment: And have you done any research on this? I am very sure, this has been asked many times in SO itself!

Comment: Isaq answer is 1...but before asking here if you google it,it is much better...show some effort...search for string pool or string object creation or read basic tutorials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String POOL in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788143/string-pool-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Questions about Java's String pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we try to create a String Object JVM first checks the String constant pool,if string doesn't exist in the pool then it will creates a new String Object `isaq` and reference maintained in the pool.The Variable S1 also refer the same String Object.

```
String s1="isaq";
```

Above statement create one String Object in String pool.
Now you are doing the

```
String s2="isaq";
```

Above statement won't create any String Object in String pool and S2 refers the same object as S1.Because JVM will check the Pool and it found String object is already present.
To Validate it you can compare String reference using `equality operator(==)`. to check whether they are referring the same String Object or not.